# Pop-up a message after redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So basically i have everything ready, but i'd like a pop-up message appear after the user redirect to another page.

so i am currently use jquery

```
$('#btn_save').click(function (){
        $('#message-box').slideDown('slow').delay(3500).slideUp('slow');
    });
```

I do not know if i should use ajax instead, i know i may use route and if(session) to do it but i am new to ajax and will happy to got an example as reference.

Many thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

This the part of my submit button which redirect the user after submit:

```
 var $btn_save = $("#btn_save");
  $btn_save.click(function () {
    //todo form validation
    if(!$(".sa-alert-name-existed").hasClass('hidden')){
      return
        }
$.post(api_submit, postData).done(function (data) {
      location.href = "/buzz#tab_pane_fbpage";
    });
```

Then we should come to the js part, which popup a message when onclick the submit button

```
$('#btn_save').click(function (){
        $('#message-box').slideDown('slow').delay(3500).slideUp('slow');
    });
    enter code here
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after redirect when the user onclick on the submit button" and this isn't "pure javascript" as you're using jQuery.

Comment: i have edited my question, thanks.

Comment: You can't use javascript from a previous page on a new page that you redirected to. In order to make this happen, you would need something that carries through to your next page, like adding a variable on the url that enables the popup on the next page or set a cookie, or a number of ways but your first page needs to set something, and your second page needs to read it.

Comment: i think "adding a variable on the url that enables the popup on the next page or set a cookie" should be an good idea, but how may i do this?

Comment: Lets be clear before we continue, when you say redirect, you do mean a page move, right? like: http://domain.com/index.html then you redirect to http://domain.com/index2.html (example). Is this part correct?

Comment: Indeed. This is what i mean.

Comment: ok, Can you include the code that does the redirect? or link to the whole thing? Basically, what you want to do is add something to the url it's being redirected to, but ... you need to know WHERE you can add that code. from the looks of it, if you press that button, you're letting the link or the form process and send the users to that destination. You can change or add something to that url with javascript, but I got to see your code to know where to put it.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106927/discussion-between-greg-borbonus-and-anson920520).

Comment: You left chat, I'll keep it open if you join it again and will reply as soon as possible.